# Programmatically add point into map at Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I want to add point into exist Google Drive map file uses JavaScript. I found related [API method](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update#examples). But I can't found specification for MIME-type 'application/vnd.google-apps.map'. What I should add to base64Data for create point?

P.S. I also didn't found possibility to download map file for investigate it's structure.

Comment: By point, you mean a Marker? There doesn't seem to be an API that can manipulate My Maps files (which I believe your inquiry is the same as the one here in [Google productforums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/PqHwHr3HLm8))

Comment: Thank you, it is fully answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an API that can manipulate My Maps files (which I believe your inquiry is the same as the one here in [Google productforums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/PqHwHr3HLm8)).